# Integrity constraint violation table: PRODUCTPERSON in statement [delete from Product where id=? and version=?]

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two classes:

***Product***

```
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "Product", indexes = {})
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Product {

     @Column(name = "name")
     private String name;

     @OneToMany(targetEntity = ProductPerson.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
     @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
     private List<ProductPerson> productPeople;

}
```

***ProductPerson***

```
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "ProductPerson", indexes = {})
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductPerson {

    @Column(name = "function")
    private String function;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Product.class)
    private Product product;

}
```

Everytime I want to delete a product I get an Exception:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Integrity constraint violation
>   FKT6TJ886WRTT5C44S9LBMPBAC1 table: PRODUCTPERSON in statement [delete
>   from Product where id=? and version=?]

The use case is that when I delete a product the productperson should also be delete. When I delete a productperson the product should stay.

I already tried this (I know it is ugly):

```
for (ProductPerson person : product.getProductPeople()) {
    person.setProduct(null);
    ProductPerson updatedPerson = productPersonRepository.update(person);
    productPersonRepository.delete(updatedPerson);
}
product.setProductPeople(new ArrayList<>());

productRepository.update(product);

productRepository.delete(product);
```

Versions:

- Hibernate: 5.2.11.Final
- Hibernate Validation: 5.4.1.Final

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are trying to delete a `Product` for which there is an existing `ProductPerson` record.

Comment: @JoeC  Because of the `Cascade.ALL` all the ProductPersons should be deleted automatically. But it doesn't work. Thats the reason why I tryed to delete all ProductPersons manually, but there is still the exception

Comment: have you had a look at the SQL statements Hibernate is creating?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli no I haven’t... but in the exception it says that the ‘delete from product ...’ statement causes it.

Comment: It is an SQL exception when you are trying to delete the entry from parent table whose child entry (foreign key) is present in another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was, that the compareTo wasn't correct.
I solved the mistake by generating the method again.